# Data Security vs Information Security

Tags: terminology

Is Information Security field and Data Security field same? If not then,

1. What is the basic difference between "Information" and "Data" in security field?
2. Is Data Security a sub-category of Information Security?
3. Is Data Security field limited at some sectors only? ---if yes then what are they?

Comment: I've never heard of the field Data Security.  I would say it's a sub-category of Information Security based on the wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security

Comment: Wikipedia has a page named after that.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_security

Comment: But isn't Data and Information are suppose to be same?

Comment: Data Security is a topic/concept for securing and protecting data.  And that concept falls under the Information Security field.  Data Security analyst in my mind is synonymous with InfoSec analyst.  That's how I view things.

Comment: This is really a terminology question that doesn't have relevance to what you need to do to protect information. Is there a reason you need to have clarity between the two terms? That might be a better question we can help with.

Comment: Probably persisted information is considered data.

Comment: Any information which can be made available & retains information on end user is data. Securing the asset data in an organization & protecting them is Data Security. Data Leakages happen in an organization & that aspect specially adheres to that of subsection of Information Security.